# Namespace name 'UnityEngine' could not be found

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I'm following the [roll-a-ball](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) tutorial from the Unity3D website. When  I try building [PlayerController.cs](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-player?playlist=17141) in MonoDevelop-Unity, I receive the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'UnityEngine' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

The smallest C# program that can reproduce this error is the single line

```
using UnityEngine;
```

I found two solutions for this problem online:

1. Reinstall Unity.
2. In the Unity editor, go to Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor, select the drop down and manually select MonoDevelop.

I have tried both and neither work.

I am using the experimental build of Unity 5.1.0f3 on Linux.

Comment: Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your Monodevelop project files and having Unity regenerate them? (Back up before doing this, if you aren't using source control.)

Comment: There's no need to build files via Monodevelop.  To play the game, just use the play button in Unity; alternatively, you can build the game in File -> Build Settings.

Comment: @LOLslowSTi I'm not sure, how can I find out? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: @user3071284 When I hit play, I receive the message "all compiler errors must be fixed before you can enter play mode." I haven't tried building in Unity, but I'll give that a try as soon as I can.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you see the "The type or namespace name 'UnityEngine' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?" error in Unity's console?  Are there any other errors in Unity's console?

Comment: @user3071284 I tried the play button again, and it wasn't compiling due to a typo! Once fixed, it builds and plays just fine. If you post your first comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to build files via Monodevelop. To play the game, just use the play button in Unity; alternatively, you can build the game in File -> Build Settings.